# Sorting date values ​in a dataframe doesn't work

Tags: pandas, sorting, date

I have the column 'Created At' in this form:

The date is in this format: `'%d/%m/%Y'` -> day, month, year

```
obj = {'Created At': ['01/01/2017', '01/02/2017', '02/01/2017', 
                      '02/02/2017', 
                      '03/01/2017', '03/02/2017','04/01/2017' ], 
       'Text': [1, 70,14,17,84,76,32]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=obj)
```

I did it, but dosen't work:

```
df.sort_values(by='Created At', inplace=True)
```

[image]
It seems that it sorts only the days and disregards the month. What do I do?

Comment: No it does sort it properly: only in case two dates are the same, it will sort on the month. That is because your dates are strings, and these are sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does sort it properly: your dates are *strings* here. Strings are sorted lexicographically. So that means that only if the first character is the same, it will look at the second character, etc.

You therefore might want to convert the column first to datetime objects:

```
df['Created At'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created At'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

then we can sort the dataframe, and obtain:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by='Created At', inplace=True)
>>> df
  Created At  Text
0 2017-01-01     1
2 2017-01-02    14
4 2017-01-03    84
6 2017-01-04    32
1 2017-02-01    70
3 2017-02-02    17
5 2017-02-03    76
```

Comment: Sorry, but i have a quenstion:

When you do it: format='%d/%m/%Y'

The result is:  Year, month, day?
For exemple:
 2017-02-02  
 2017-02-03

Comment: @Gizelly: the format specifies how we *parse* the strings to a `datetime` object. So once it is parsed, the datetime objects, are represented as yyyy-mm-dd. These are not strings anymore, but datetime objects. So it makes calculations, etc. on dates more convenient.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for teach me a new concept! I had no idea about lexicography. You helped me so much!

Comment: Missing `inplace` was the issue in my case.